# The probability TRIANGLES starts with 3 vowels

Tags: probability

My question say,

**If all the letters of TRIANGLES are placed in a row, find the probability that the resulting word:**

**b) starts with the three vowels in a row**

I know that there are 3 vowels in the word, so would my answer be 3/9? Or would this be solved differently? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you answer these questions: How many ways can you permute the letters of TRIANGLES? How many of these permutations start with a consonant? How many start with 3 vowels?

Comment: I have learned about Permutations but it is something I really struggle with. it is why I am asking

Comment: What have you learned about them?

Comment: Not a lot. Do you know how to solve this? if so could you provide some clarification to the question?

Comment: For the first part, you have to divide the number of arrangements in which the first letter is a consonant by the number of arrangements of the letters of the word TRIANGLES.  How many ways can the letters of the word TRIANGLES be arranged?  For the favorable cases, how many ways can you select a consonant to be the first letter?  How many ways can you arrange the remaining letters?

Comment: Regarding your edited question: no, the answer is not 3/9. My answer below -- specifically, Q3 (and the parts leading up to it) spell out how to find the answer. Have you consulted those?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any combinations or permutations here.

For part (a): there are $9$ letters, and $6$ of them are consonants. So the probability that the first letter is a consonant is $\frac69$.

For part (b), use the above principle to answer these three questions:

1. What is the probability that the first letter is a vowel?
2. If the first letter is a vowel, what is the probability that the second letter is a vowel?
3. If the first two letters are vowels, what is the probability that the third letter is a vowel?

Now just multiply these three probabilities together.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to illustrate the concepts with a simpler example. The best way to use this is definitely to try to solve these small problems on your own, and consult the solutions (covered by spoiler tags) only when you have an answer or are stuck.

Consider rearrangements of the word LEMON.

**Q1:** How many ways are there to rearrange the letters in LEMON?

> There are $5! = \fbox{120}$ ways to rearrange the letters in LEMON. Think about it letter by letter; in the first slot, you have 5 letters to choose from. Once you've selected one, you then have 4 letters for the second slot, then 3 for the third, and so on. The total number of ways to put down all five letters is therefore $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 5!$.

**Q2:** How many ways are there to rearrange the letters in LEMON so that N is the first letter?

> Similar strategy as before: in the first slot we must put a N, so there's no choice there. There are 4 choices remaining for the second slot, then 3 for the third, and so on. Thus, there are $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 4! = \fbox{24}$ of such rearrangements.

**Q2.5** If the letters of LEMON are rearranged, what is the probability that N is the first letter?

> This is a ratio if the previous two counting problems. Of the 120 ways to rearrange LEMON, 24 have N as the first letter: hence, the answer is $24/120 = \fbox{1/5}$. Notice how reasonable that answer is in hindsight!

**Q3:** If we rearrange the letters in LEMON, what is the probability that the two vowels are at the front?

> Let's count the ways to have the vowels in the front first. Again, think letter by letter. The first spot has two possible choices (E or O); the second spot then has just 1. There are 3 remaining choices for the third spot, and 2 and 1 for the fourth and fifth spots, respectively. The total number of ways is therefore $2 \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 12$. Hence, the probability is $\fbox{12/120 = 1/10}$.